# SELECT DISTINCT on two columns

Tags: sql, distinct

I currently have a query that is getting the distinct values of two columns using a union, but this is only showing 1 field in the return what i am wanting to do is add the id(PK) column so i can make a sort, this will allow the latest conversation to be top of the list.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `to` 
FROM  `inbox` 
WHERE  `from` =  '$customer'
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT  `from` 
FROM  `inbox` 
WHERE  `to` =  '$customer'
```

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result!

Comment: I don't understand your question, even after you edited your question. Not clear. How about an example. Input, Output.

Comment: Your current query would return exatcly the same as `SELECT '$customer', '$customer'`

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is `UNION`

```
SELECT DISTINCT `from`
FROM   `inbox`
WHERE  `from` = '$customer'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT `to`
FROM   `inbox`
WHERE  `to` = '$customer'
```

[`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) combines two select outputs into one, ignoring duplicates from second one.

Your second question to got latest conversations can be solved by this query:

```
SELECT `name`, MAX(`id`) id FROM
(
    SELECT `from` as `name`, `id`
    FROM   `inbox`
    WHERE  `from` = '$customer'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `to` as `name`, `id`
    FROM   `inbox`
    WHERE  `to` = '$customer'
) DerivedTable
GROUP BY `name`
ORDER BY MAX(`id`)
```

Comment: this way, if a name is both in the `from` and `to` columns, they'll appear in your output twice.

Comment: @MichielB, no, that would be the case if it was a `UNION ALL`, a `UNION` removes duplicates. Which also makes `SELECT DISTINCT` unnecessary.

Comment: You must probably switch `to` and `from` in your selects: `SELECT to
FROM   inbox
WHERE  from = '$customer'
UNION
SELECT from
FROM   inbox
WHERE  to = '$customer'` Otherwise the result is just `'$customer'`

Comment: @ginden thanks so much, and with the help of dnoeth this worked

Comment: Is it possible to add in the id column into that Query so i can order by the ID so the newest conversations go top ?

Comment: It's more complicated than just adding `id` there. If you edit a question I would add query to my answer.

Comment: I have added second answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to add another column you must switch to GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT:

```
SELECT  -- return the "other" column  
   CASE WHEN `from` = '$customer' THEN `to` 
        WHEN `to` = '$customer' THEN `from` 
   END AS usr, 
   MAX(id) AS max_id
FROM  `inbox` 
WHERE `from` =  '$customer'
   OR `to` =  '$customer'
GROUP BY
--   CASE WHEN `from` = '$customer' THEN `to` 
--       WHEN `to` = '$customer' THEN `from` 
--   END
-- afaik MySQL allows using the alias usr instead
   usr
ORDER BY max_id DESC
```